# How package multiple openxml format xml to one xlsx file without OpenXml SDK just using string?

Tags: c#, .net, openxml

How package multiple openxml format xml to one xlsx file without OpenXml SDK just using string?

There're three xml like image, I'd like to package then to one xlsx `without OpenXml SDK`.

[image]

I've tried create file and folder like
[image]
package them to `zip` file and rename `Test.xlsx`
[image]
but it not work and show file error.
[image]

Three xml files data:

`/docProps/app.xml`

```
<ap:Properties xmlns:vt="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/docPropsVTypes" xmlns:ap="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/extended-properties">
  <ap:Application>Microsoft Excel</ap:Application>
  <ap:DocSecurity>0</ap:DocSecurity>
  <ap:ScaleCrop>false</ap:ScaleCrop>
  <ap:HeadingPairs>
    <vt:vector baseType="variant" size="2">
      <vt:variant>
        <vt:lpstr>Worksheets</vt:lpstr>
      </vt:variant>
      <vt:variant>
        <vt:i4>1</vt:i4>
      </vt:variant>
    </vt:vector>
  </ap:HeadingPairs>
  <ap:TitlesOfParts>
    <vt:vector baseType="lpstr" size="1">
      <vt:lpstr>Sheet1</vt:lpstr>
    </vt:vector>
  </ap:TitlesOfParts>
  <ap:Company />
  <ap:LinksUpToDate>false</ap:LinksUpToDate>
  <ap:SharedDoc>false</ap:SharedDoc>
  <ap:HyperlinksChanged>false</ap:HyperlinksChanged>
  <ap:AppVersion>16.0300</ap:AppVersion>
</ap:Properties>
```

`/docProps/core.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<cp:coreProperties xmlns:cp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/metadata/core-properties" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" xmlns:dcmitype="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><dc:creator>Wei</dc:creator><cp:lastModifiedBy>Wei</cp:lastModifiedBy><dcterms:created xsi:type="dcterms:W3CDTF">2015-06-05T18:17:20Z</dcterms:created><dcterms:modified xsi:type="dcterms:W3CDTF">2021-02-23T07:31:31Z</dcterms:modified></cp:coreProperties>
```

`/xl/workbook.xml`

```
<x:styleSheet xmlns:x14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2009/9/main" xmlns:x15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2010/11/main" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:x14ac="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2009/9/ac" xmlns:x16r2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2015/02/main" xmlns:xr="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2014/revision" mc:Ignorable="x14ac x16r2 xr" xmlns:x="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
  <x:fonts count="2" x14ac:knownFonts="1">
    <x:font>
      <x:sz val="11" />
      <x:color theme="1" />
      <x:name val="Calibri" />
      <x:family val="2" />
      <x:scheme val="minor" />
    </x:font>
    <x:font>
      <x:sz val="8" />
      <x:name val="Calibri" />
      <x:family val="2" />
      <x:scheme val="minor" />
    </x:font>
  </x:fonts>
  <x:fills count="2">
    <x:fill>
      <x:patternFill patternType="none" />
    </x:fill>
    <x:fill>
      <x:patternFill patternType="gray125" />
    </x:fill>
  </x:fills>
  <x:borders count="1">
    <x:border>
      <x:left />
      <x:right />
      <x:top />
      <x:bottom />
      <x:diagonal />
    </x:border>
  </x:borders>
  <x:cellStyleXfs count="1">
    <x:xf numFmtId="0" fontId="0" fillId="0" borderId="0" />
  </x:cellStyleXfs>
  <x:cellXfs count="1">
    <x:xf numFmtId="0" fontId="0" fillId="0" borderId="0" xfId="0" />
  </x:cellXfs>
  <x:cellStyles count="1">
    <x:cellStyle name="Normal" xfId="0" builtinId="0" />
  </x:cellStyles>
  <x:dxfs count="0" />
  <x:tableStyles count="0" defaultTableStyle="TableStyleMedium2" defaultPivotStyle="PivotStyleLight16" />
  <x:extLst>
    <x:ext xmlns:x14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2009/9/main" uri="{EB79DEF2-80B8-43e5-95BD-54CBDDF9020C}">
      <x14:slicerStyles defaultSlicerStyle="SlicerStyleLight1" />
    </x:ext>
    <x:ext xmlns:x15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2010/11/main" uri="{9260A510-F301-46a8-8635-F512D64BE5F5}">
      <x15:timelineStyles defaultTimelineStyle="TimeSlicerStyleLight1" />
    </x:ext>
  </x:extLst>
</x:styleSheet>
<a:theme xmlns:thm15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/thememl/2012/main" xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" name="Office Theme">
  <a:themeElements>
    <a:clrScheme name="Office">
      <a:dk1>
        <a:sysClr val="windowText" lastClr="000000" />
      </a:dk1>
      <a:lt1>
        <a:sysClr val="window" lastClr="FFFFFF" />
      </a:lt1>
      <a:dk2>
        <a:srgbClr val="44546A" />
      </a:dk2>
      <a:lt2>
        <a:srgbClr val="E7E6E6" />
      </a:lt2>
      <a:accent1>
        <a:srgbClr val="5B9BD5" />
      </a:accent1>
      <a:accent2>
        <a:srgbClr val="ED7D31" />
      </a:accent2>
      <a:accent3>
        <a:srgbClr val="A5A5A5" />
      </a:accent3>
      <a:accent4>
        <a:srgbClr val="FFC000" />
      </a:accent4>
      <a:accent5>
        <a:srgbClr val="4472C4" />
      </a:accent5>
      <a:accent6>
        <a:srgbClr val="70AD47" />
      </a:accent6>
      <a:hlink>
        <a:srgbClr val="0563C1" />
      </a:hlink>
      <a:folHlink>
        <a:srgbClr val="954F72" />
      </a:folHlink>
    </a:clrScheme>
    <a:fontScheme name="Office">
      <a:majorFont>
        <a:latin typeface="Calibri Light" panose="020F0302020204030204" />
        <a:ea typeface="" />
        <a:cs typeface="" />
        <a:font script="Jpan" typeface="游ゴシック Light" />
        <a:font script="Hang" typeface="맑은 고딕" />
        <a:font script="Hans" typeface="等线 Light" />
        <a:font script="Hant" typeface="新細明體" />
        <a:font script="Arab" typeface="Times New Roman" />
        <a:font script="Hebr" typeface="Times New Roman" />
        <a:font script="Thai" typeface="Tahoma" />
        <a:font script="Ethi" typeface="Nyala" />
        <a:font script="Beng" typeface="Vrinda" />
        <a:font script="Gujr" typeface="Shruti" />
        <a:font script="Khmr" typeface="MoolBoran" />
        <a:font script="Knda" typeface="Tunga" />
        <a:font script="Guru" typeface="Raavi" />
        <a:font script="Cans" typeface="Euphemia" />
        <a:font script="Cher" typeface="Plantagenet Cherokee" />
        <a:font script="Yiii" typeface="Microsoft Yi Baiti" />
        <a:font script="Tibt" typeface="Microsoft Himalaya" />
        <a:font script="Thaa" typeface="MV Boli" />
        <a:font script="Deva" typeface="Mangal" />
        <a:font script="Telu" typeface="Gautami" />
        <a:font script="Taml" typeface="Latha" />
        <a:font script="Syrc" typeface="Estrangelo Edessa" />
        <a:font script="Orya" typeface="Kalinga" />
        <a:font script="Mlym" typeface="Kartika" />
        <a:font script="Laoo" typeface="DokChampa" />
        <a:font script="Sinh" typeface="Iskoola Pota" />
        <a:font script="Mong" typeface="Mongolian Baiti" />
        <a:font script="Viet" typeface="Times New Roman" />
        <a:font script="Uigh" typeface="Microsoft Uighur" />
        <a:font script="Geor" typeface="Sylfaen" />
      </a:majorFont>
      <a:minorFont>
        <a:latin typeface="Calibri" panose="020F0502020204030204" />
        <a:ea typeface="" />
        <a:cs typeface="" />
        <a:font script="Jpan" typeface="游ゴシック" />
        <a:font script="Hang" typeface="맑은 고딕" />
        <a:font script="Hans" typeface="等线" />
        <a:font script="Hant" typeface="新細明體" />
        <a:font script="Arab" typeface="Arial" />
        <a:font script="Hebr" typeface="Arial" />
        <a:font script="Thai" typeface="Tahoma" />
        <a:font script="Ethi" typeface="Nyala" />
        <a:font script="Beng" typeface="Vrinda" />
        <a:font script="Gujr" typeface="Shruti" />
        <a:font script="Khmr" typeface="DaunPenh" />
        <a:font script="Knda" typeface="Tunga" />
        <a:font script="Guru" typeface="Raavi" />
        <a:font script="Cans" typeface="Euphemia" />
        <a:font script="Cher" typeface="Plantagenet Cherokee" />
        <a:font script="Yiii" typeface="Microsoft Yi Baiti" />
        <a:font script="Tibt" typeface="Microsoft Himalaya" />
        <a:font script="Thaa" typeface="MV Boli" />
        <a:font script="Deva" typeface="Mangal" />
        <a:font script="Telu" typeface="Gautami" />
        <a:font script="Taml" typeface="Latha" />
        <a:font script="Syrc" typeface="Estrangelo Edessa" />
        <a:font script="Orya" typeface="Kalinga" />
        <a:font script="Mlym" typeface="Kartika" />
        <a:font script="Laoo" typeface="DokChampa" />
        <a:font script="Sinh" typeface="Iskoola Pota" />
        <a:font script="Mong" typeface="Mongolian Baiti" />
        <a:font script="Viet" typeface="Arial" />
        <a:font script="Uigh" typeface="Microsoft Uighur" />
        <a:font script="Geor" typeface="Sylfaen" />
      </a:minorFont>
    </a:fontScheme>
    <a:fmtScheme name="Office">
      <a:fillStyleLst>
        <a:solidFill>
          <a:schemeClr val="phClr" />
        </a:solidFill>
        <a:gradFill rotWithShape="1">
          <a:gsLst>
            <a:gs pos="0">
              <a:schemeClr val="phClr">
                <a:lumMod val="110000" />
                <a:satMod val="105000" />
                <a:tint val="67000" />
              </a:schemeClr>
            </a:gs>
            <a:gs pos="50000">
              <a:schemeClr val="phClr">
                <a:lumMod val="105000" />
                <a:satMod val="103000" />
                <a:tint val="73000" />
              </a:schemeClr>
            </a:gs>
            <a:gs pos="100000">
              <a:schemeClr val="phClr">
                <a:lumMod val="105000" />
                <a:satMod val="109000" />
                <a:tint val="81000" />
              </a:schemeClr>
            </a:gs>
          </a:gsLst>
          <a:lin ang="5400000" scaled="0" />
        </a:gradFill>
        <a:gradFill rotWithShape="1">
          <a:gsLst>
            <a:gs pos="0">
              <a:schemeClr val="phClr">
                <a:satMod val="103000" />
                <a:lumMod val="102000" />
                <a:tint val="94000" />
              </a:schemeClr>
            </a:gs>
            <a:gs pos="50000">
              <a:schemeClr val="phClr">
                <a:satMod val="110000" />
                <a:lumMod val="100000" />
                <a:shade val="100000" />
              </a:schemeClr>
            </a:gs>
            <a:gs pos="100000">
              <a:schemeClr val="phClr">
                <a:lumMod val="99000" />
                <a:satMod val="120000" />
                <a:shade val="78000" />
              </a:schemeClr>
            </a:gs>
          </a:gsLst>
          <a:lin ang="5400000" scaled="0" />
        </a:gradFill>
      </a:fillStyleLst>
      <a:lnStyleLst>
        <a:ln w="6350" cap="flat" cmpd="sng" algn="ctr">
          <a:solidFill>
            <a:schemeClr val="phClr" />
          </a:solidFill>
          <a:prstDash val="solid" />
          <a:miter lim="800000" />
        </a:ln>
        <a:ln w="12700" cap="flat" cmpd="sng" algn="ctr">
          <a:solidFill>
            <a:schemeClr val="phClr" />
          </a:solidFill>
          <a:prstDash val="solid" />
          <a:miter lim="800000" />
        </a:ln>
        <a:ln w="19050" cap="flat" cmpd="sng" algn="ctr">
          <a:solidFill>
            <a:schemeClr val="phClr" />
          </a:solidFill>
          <a:prstDash val="solid" />
          <a:miter lim="800000" />
        </a:ln>
      </a:lnStyleLst>
      <a:effectStyleLst>
        <a:effectStyle>
          <a:effectLst />
        </a:effectStyle>
        <a:effectStyle>
          <a:effectLst />
        </a:effectStyle>
        <a:effectStyle>
          <a:effectLst>
            <a:outerShdw blurRad="57150" dist="19050" dir="5400000" algn="ctr" rotWithShape="0">
              <a:srgbClr val="000000">
                <a:alpha val="63000" />
              </a:srgbClr>
            </a:outerShdw>
          </a:effectLst>
        </a:effectStyle>
      </a:effectStyleLst>
      <a:bgFillStyleLst>
        <a:solidFill>
          <a:schemeClr val="phClr" />
        </a:solidFill>
        <a:solidFill>
          <a:schemeClr val="phClr">
            <a:tint val="95000" />
            <a:satMod val="170000" />
          </a:schemeClr>
        </a:solidFill>
        <a:gradFill rotWithShape="1">
          <a:gsLst>
            <a:gs pos="0">
              <a:schemeClr val="phClr">
                <a:tint val="93000" />
                <a:satMod val="150000" />
                <a:shade val="98000" />
                <a:lumMod val="102000" />
              </a:schemeClr>
            </a:gs>
            <a:gs pos="50000">
              <a:schemeClr val="phClr">
                <a:tint val="98000" />
                <a:satMod val="130000" />
                <a:shade val="90000" />
                <a:lumMod val="103000" />
              </a:schemeClr>
            </a:gs>
            <a:gs pos="100000">
              <a:schemeClr val="phClr">
                <a:shade val="63000" />
                <a:satMod val="120000" />
              </a:schemeClr>
            </a:gs>
          </a:gsLst>
          <a:lin ang="5400000" scaled="0" />
        </a:gradFill>
      </a:bgFillStyleLst>
    </a:fmtScheme>
  </a:themeElements>
  <a:objectDefaults />
  <a:extraClrSchemeLst />
  <a:extLst>
    <a:ext uri="{05A4C25C-085E-4340-85A3-A5531E510DB2}">
      <thm15:themeFamily xmlns:thm15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/thememl/2012/main" name="Office Theme" id="{62F939B6-93AF-4DB8-9C6B-D6C7DFDC589F}" vid="{4A3C46E8-61CC-4603-A589-7422A47A8E4A}" />
    </a:ext>
  </a:extLst>
</a:theme>
<x:worksheet xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:x14ac="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2009/9/ac" xmlns:xr="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2014/revision" xmlns:xr2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2015/revision2" xmlns:xr3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2016/revision3" xr:uid="{00000000-0001-0000-0000-000000000000}" mc:Ignorable="x14ac xr xr2 xr3" xmlns:x="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
  <x:dimension ref="A1:C4" />
  <x:sheetViews>
    <x:sheetView tabSelected="1" workbookViewId="0">
      <x:selection activeCell="E5" sqref="E5" />
    </x:sheetView>
  </x:sheetViews>
  <x:sheetFormatPr defaultRowHeight="14.4" x14ac:dyDescent="0.3" />
  <x:sheetData>
    <x:row r="1" spans="1:3" x14ac:dyDescent="0.3">
      <x:c r="A1" t="s">
        <x:v>0</x:v>
      </x:c>
      <x:c r="B1" t="s">
        <x:v>1</x:v>
      </x:c>
      <x:c r="C1" t="s">
        <x:v>2</x:v>
      </x:c>
    </x:row>
    <x:row r="2" spans="1:3" x14ac:dyDescent="0.3">
      <x:c r="A2" t="s">
        <x:v>3</x:v>
      </x:c>
      <x:c r="B2" t="s">
        <x:v>4</x:v>
      </x:c>
      <x:c r="C2" t="s">
        <x:v>5</x:v>
      </x:c>
    </x:row>
    <x:row r="3" spans="1:3" x14ac:dyDescent="0.3">
      <x:c r="A3" t="s">
        <x:v>6</x:v>
      </x:c>
      <x:c r="B3" t="s">
        <x:v>7</x:v>
      </x:c>
      <x:c r="C3" t="s">
        <x:v>8</x:v>
      </x:c>
    </x:row>
    <x:row r="4" spans="1:3" x14ac:dyDescent="0.3">
      <x:c r="A4" t="s">
        <x:v>9</x:v>
      </x:c>
      <x:c r="B4" t="s">
        <x:v>10</x:v>
      </x:c>
      <x:c r="C4" t="s">
        <x:v>11</x:v>
      </x:c>
    </x:row>
  </x:sheetData>
  <x:phoneticPr fontId="1" type="noConversion" />
  <x:pageMargins left="0.7" right="0.7" top="0.75" bottom="0.75" header="0.3" footer="0.3" />
</x:worksheet>
<x:sst count="12" uniqueCount="12" xmlns:x="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
  <x:si>
    <x:t>A1</x:t>
  </x:si>
  <x:si>
    <x:t>B1</x:t>
  </x:si>
  <x:si>
    <x:t>C1</x:t>
  </x:si>
  <x:si>
    <x:t>A2</x:t>
  </x:si>
  <x:si>
    <x:t>B2</x:t>
  </x:si>
  <x:si>
    <x:t>C2</x:t>
  </x:si>
  <x:si>
    <x:t>A3</x:t>
  </x:si>
  <x:si>
    <x:t>B3</x:t>
  </x:si>
  <x:si>
    <x:t>C3</x:t>
  </x:si>
  <x:si>
    <x:t>A4</x:t>
  </x:si>
  <x:si>
    <x:t>B4</x:t>
  </x:si>
  <x:si>
    <x:t>C4</x:t>
  </x:si>
</x:sst>
<x:workbook xmlns:x15ac="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2010/11/ac" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:x15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2010/11/main" xmlns:xr="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2014/revision" xmlns:xr6="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2016/revision6" xmlns:xr10="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2016/revision10" xmlns:xr2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2015/revision2" mc:Ignorable="x15 xr xr6 xr10 xr2" xmlns:x="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
  <x:fileVersion appName="xl" lastEdited="7" lowestEdited="6" rupBuild="23628" />
  <x:workbookPr />
  <mc:AlternateContent xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006">
    <mc:Choice Requires="x15">
      <x15ac:absPath xmlns:x15ac="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2010/11/ac" url="D:\demos\2021-02-23 OpenXmlSheetDemo\" />
    </mc:Choice>
  </mc:AlternateContent>
  <xr:revisionPtr revIDLastSave="0" documentId="13_ncr:1_{E054103D-6836-43D1-8070-43C5CB7C85D0}" xr6:coauthVersionLast="46" xr6:coauthVersionMax="46" xr10:uidLastSave="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}" />
  <x:bookViews>
    <x:workbookView xWindow="-108" yWindow="-108" windowWidth="23256" windowHeight="12720" xr2:uid="{00000000-000D-0000-FFFF-FFFF00000000}" />
  </x:bookViews>
  <x:sheets>
    <x:sheet name="Sheet1" sheetId="1" r:id="rId1" />
  </x:sheets>
  <x:calcPr calcId="162913" />
  <x:extLst>
    <x:ext xmlns:x15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2010/11/main" uri="{140A7094-0E35-4892-8432-C4D2E57EDEB5}">
      <x15:workbookPr chartTrackingRefBase="1" />
    </x:ext>
  </x:extLst>
</x:workbook>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve problem by below way.

Step1.  Folder tree path have to like :

```
│   [Content_Types].xml
│
├───docProps
│       app.xml
│       core.xml
│
├───xl
│   │   sharedStrings.xml
│   │   styles.xml
│   │   workbook.xml
│   │
│   ├───theme
│   │       theme1.xml
│   │
│   ├───worksheets
│   │       sheet1.xml
│   │
│   └───_rels
│           workbook.xml.rels
│
└───_rels
        .rels
```

Step2. then from root folder path to zip all folder and files to zip file and rename to `Demo.xlsx`

Result :

[image]